# SSL certificate verification failure in jekyll-github-metadata

Tags: ruby, ssl, jekyll, github-pages

When trying to build my Github Pages site locally, the jekyll-github-metadata plugin is causing SSL cert errors. The site has no problem rendering on github pages, so it must be a configuration issue on my end.

I am aware of [this issue](https://superdevresources.com/ssl-error-ruby-gems-windows/), and while it does not appear to be exactly the same (I have no trouble installing gems, only using the github metadata plugin) I added [the certificate](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem) to my environment variables, but it changed nothing.

What do I need to change for the SSL cert to verify properly?

---

## Appendicies

### Versions

Ruby: 2.2.4 (x86)
Jekyll: 3.0.5
jekyll-github-metadata 1.11.1

### The Error message

```
Liquid Exception: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed in _layouts/default.html
jekyll 3.0.5 | Error:  SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

### The stack trace

```
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (Faraday::SSLError)
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `block in connect'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/timeout.rb:73:in `timeout'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1375:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:1133:in `get'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:80:in `perform_request'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:40:in `block in call'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:87:in `with_net_http_connection'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:32:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/response.rb:8:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/octokit-4.3.0/lib/octokit/middleware/follow_redirects.rb:73:in `perform_with_redirection'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/octokit-4.3.0/lib/octokit/middleware/follow_redirects.rb:61:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:140:in `get'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sawyer-0.7.0/lib/sawyer/agent.rb:94:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/octokit-4.3.0/lib/octokit/connection.rb:154:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/octokit-4.3.0/lib/octokit/connection.rb:19:in `get'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/octokit-4.3.0/lib/octokit/client/pages.rb:15:in `pages'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/client.rb:52:in `public_send'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/client.rb:52:in `block in method_missing'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/client.rb:64:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/client.rb:64:in `save_from_errors'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/client.rb:52:in `method_missing'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/repository.rb:167:in `block in cname'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/value.rb:27:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/value.rb:27:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/repository.rb:189:in `memoize_value'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/repository.rb:165:in `cname'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/repository.rb:157:in `pages_url'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata.rb:106:in `block in init!'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/value.rb:29:in`call'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/value.rb:29:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-github-metadata-1.11.1/lib/jekyll-github-metadata/value.rb:51:in `to_liquid'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/variable_lookup.rb:49:in `block in evaluate'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/variable_lookup.rb:38:in `each_index'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/variable_lookup.rb:38:in `evaluate'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/context.rb:168:in `evaluate'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/variable.rb:110:in `block in evaluate_filter_expressions'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/variable.rb:110:in `map'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/variable.rb:110:in `evaluate_filter_expressions'

    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/variable.rb:87:in `block in render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/variable.rb:86:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/variable.rb:86:in `inject'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/variable.rb:86:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/tags/assign.rb:26:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:151:in `render_token'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/profiler/hooks.rb:5:in `block in render_token_with_profiling'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/profiler.rb:80:in `profile_token_render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/profiler/hooks.rb:4:in `render_token_with_profiling'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:135:in `block in render_all'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:122:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:122:in `render_all'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:108:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/template.rb:210:in `block in render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/template.rb:262:in `with_profiling'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/template.rb:209:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/template.rb:222:in `render!'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-seo-tag-1.4.0/lib/jekyll-seo-tag.rb:17:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:151:in `render_token'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/profiler/hooks.rb:5:in `block in render_token_with_profiling'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/profiler.rb:80:in `profile_token_render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/profiler/hooks.rb:4:in `render_token_with_profiling'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:135:in `block in render_all'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:122:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:122:in `render_all'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/block.rb:108:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/template.rb:210:in `block in render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/template.rb:262:in `with_profiling'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/template.rb:209:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/liquid-3.0.6/lib/liquid/template.rb:222:in `render!'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:28:in `block (2 levels) in render!'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:36:in `measure_bytes'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:27:in `block in render!'

    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:43:in `measure_time'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/liquid_renderer/file.rb:26:in `render!'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:105:in `render_liquid'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:147:in `place_in_layouts'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/renderer.rb:69:in `run'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:171:in `block (2 levels) in render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:169:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:169:in `block in render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:168:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:168:in `render'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/site.rb:59:in `process'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:60:in `build'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:35:in `process'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:26:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.0.5/bin/jekyll:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from C:/Ruby22/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you manage to find the fix to this?

Comment: Not as such. Because of this and other problems, I gave up on doing this through ruby on Windows, and now run it through the Windows subsystem for Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Following the instructions from [here](https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550#the-manual-way-boring), I managed to get it working.

> Download the cacert.pem file from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem.
>   Save this file to C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem.
>
> Now make ruby aware of your certificate authority bundle by setting
>   SSL_CERT_FILE. To set this in your current command prompt session,
>   type:
>
> `set SSL_CERT_FILE=C:\RailsInstaller\cacert.pem`

Comment: I imagine this is the answer for most cases, which is why it was what I found when searching. The question was what I might be doing wrong such that it does not work.