# Github metadata preventing Jekyll auto-regenerate

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

I'm running Jekyll 3.2.1 on Windows 10. Everything with Jekyll is working, it's hosted on Github etc. EXCEPT if I want a post to update to the newest version I have to stop the server and start it again (rather than just save and reload browser).

I'm aware of these existing questions: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219213/ssl-certifacte-verification-failiure-in-jekyll-github-metadata), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559218/using-github-repository-metadata-with-jekyll-javascript) but they are dealing with different errors.

Here's my error:

`Regenerating: 1 file(s) changed at 2016-09-17 10:47:31            Reading: _posts/2016-09-13-up-and-running-with-jekyll.md
           Reading: _posts/2016-09-14-jekyll-setup-windows-github.md
           Reading: _posts/2016-09-16-javascript-exercise-alternating-numbers.md
           Reading: _posts/2016-09-17-javascript-object-keys-iteration.md
   GitHub Metadata: Initializing...
...error:
             Error: No such file or directory - git rev-parse HEAD
             Error: Run jekyll build --trace for more information.`

When I test for: echo %JEKYLL_GITHUB_TOKEN% it returns the correct value.

HOWEVER, when I test for: ruby -rnet/https -e "Net::HTTP.get URI('https://github.com')" --verbose

I get:

`C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:895: warning: instance variable @npn_protocols not initialized
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:895: warning: instance variable @npn_select_cb not initialized`

Question: How do I fix this so auto-regenerate doesn't get an error?

Here's my gem list:

`activesupport (5.0.0.1, 4.2.7)
addressable (2.4.0)
bigdecimal (1.2.7, 1.2.6)
bundle (0.0.1)
bundler (1.13.1, 1.5.0)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
colorator (1.1.0, 0.1)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
directory_watcher (1.4.1)
ethon (0.9.0)
execjs (2.7.0)
faraday (0.9.2)
ffi (1.9.14 x64-mingw32)
forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
gemoji (2.1.0)
github-pages (96, 95)
github-pages-health-check (1.2.0)
html-pipeline (2.4.2)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.6, 0.4.3)
jekyll (3.2.1, 3.1.6)
jekyll-coffeescript (1.0.1)
jekyll-feed (0.7.0, 0.5.1)
jekyll-gist (1.4.0)
jekyll-github-metadata (2.0.2)
jekyll-mentions (1.2.0)
jekyll-paginate (1.1.0)
jekyll-redirect-from (0.11.0)
jekyll-sass-converter (1.3.0)
jekyll-seo-tag (2.0.0)
jekyll-sitemap (0.11.0, 0.10.0)
jekyll-watch (1.5.0)
jemoji (0.7.0)
json (1.8.3, 1.8.1)
kramdown (1.11.1)
liquid (3.0.6)
listen (3.1.5, 3.0.6)
mercenary (0.3.6)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minima (1.2.0, 1.1.0)
minitest (5.9.0)
multipart-post (2.0.0)
net-dns (0.8.0)
nokogiri (1.6.8 x64-mingw32)
octokit (4.3.0)
pathutil (0.14.0)
pkg-config (1.1.7)
power_assert (0.3.1)
psych (2.0.8)
public_suffix (2.0.2, 1.5.3)
rake (11.2.2, 10.4.2)
rb-fsevent (0.9.7)
rb-inotify (0.9.7)
rdoc (4.2.2, 4.2.0)
rouge (2.0.6, 1.11.1)
ruby_dep (1.4.0)
safe_yaml (1.0.4)
sass (3.4.22)
sawyer (0.7.0)
terminal-table (1.7.2)
test-unit (3.2.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
typhoeus (1.1.0, 0.8.0)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
unicode-display_width (1.1.1)
wdm (0.1.1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Windows CMD? If so try the shell you get with the [Github desktop app](https://desktop.github.com/)

Comment: you're amazing! jesus christ this was driving me nuts! now i've gotta figure out why kramdown only applies like one or two code tags.